# parsing html using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a newbie in Python and have a simple question on parsing html. I am using Beautiful soup to get upto this point. I want to extract the taxes and maintenance from the below. I am not sure how to do this.

> div class="estimated_payment clickable overlay_trigger hidden-xs"
>   id="overlay_trigger_1255749" se:behavior="monthly_payment"
>   se:monthly_payment:attributes='{"id":1255749,"taxes":3682.0,"price":5500000,"maintenance":1875.0,"mortgage_rate":3.5,"mortgage_term":30,"down_payment_amount":1100000.0,"down_payment_rate":20.0,"min_down_payment_rate":20.0,"min_down_payment_amount":1100000.0}'>
>   Est.
>   Payment: **$0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps:

- locate the element and extract the `se:monthly_payment:attributes` attribute value
- load it via [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to a Python dictionary and get the desired amounts by keys

Implementation:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<div class="estimated_payment clickable overlay_trigger hidden-xs"
     id="overlay_trigger_1255749"
     se:behavior="monthly_payment"
     se:monthly_payment:attributes='{"id":1255749,"taxes":3682.0,"price":5500000,"maintenance":1875.0,"mortgage_rate":3.5,"mortgage_term":30,"down_payment_amount":1100000.0,"down_payment_rate":20.0,"min_down_payment_rate":20.0,"min_down_payment_amount":1100000.0}'>
     Est. Payment: $0
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

attr_value = soup.select_one(".estimated_payment")["se:monthly_payment:attributes"]
payment_data = json.loads(attr_value)

print(payment_data["taxes"])
print(payment_data["maintenance"])
```

Prints:

```
3682.0
1875.0
```

Comment: Thanks so much! do you have a good source that can help me with these basics

Comment: @qfd well, the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is really detailed and covers a lot. Also, you can get all `beautifulsoup` tagged questions here on SO, sort them by votes and study - this is usually a good way to get introduced to the most common use cases and problems coming up while working with the library. Thanks.

Comment: @qfd please accept the answer to close this question.